# Polymer 1.0: Dynamic iron-meta values and syncronization

Tags: javascript, polymer-1.0

Looking for some advice on Polymer and how to share between elements correctly.

My goal is to load and process a set of data one time and share that data between polymer components.  I've tried creating a polymer element 'load-data' to fetch the data, format the data, and then store the results as iron-meta tags.

```
<dom-module id="load-data">
  <template>
    ...
    <div id="metatags"></div>
    <iron-ajax ....on-response="handleResponse"></iron-ajax>
  </template>
</dom-module>

<script>
  Polymer({

    is: 'load-data',

    ...
    handleResponse: function (data) {

      // do stuff
      var processed_data = document.createElement('iron-meta');
      processed_data .setAttribute('key','processed-data');
      processed_data .setAttribute('value',JSON.stringify(processed_data));
      this.$.metatags.appendChild(processed_data); // metatags refers to a div in local dom
      ...
    }
  }
</script>
```

I then include 'load-data' in other custom elements assuming i'll now have access to the data i need (via iron-meta-query).

```
<dom-module id="a-visualization">
  <template>
    ...
    <load-data></load-data>
    ...
  </template>
</dom-module>

<script>
  Polymer({

    is: 'a-visualization',

    ...
</script>
```

Finally, i use my element multiple times on my webpage...and that's where i discover the issues.

```
...
<a-visualization id="first"></a-visualization>
<a-visualization id="second"></a-visualization>
...
```

So, when the first a-visualization element is loaded, load-data is created and makes an asynchronous call to get data.  The browser continues executing and loads the second a-visualization element.  At this point, ideally i'd want the second element to wait until data is loaded by the first element...an operation that is currently in progress.

I could set a flag when load-data is first encountered and check that flag the second time load-data is called, but I'm still left not knowing when to continue processing the second element.  From the flag i can tell that a loading process has started...but unless i poll/sleep/poll which feels like a bad approach, the second element doesn't know when to start processing again.  I think I really need to have the first instance of load-data execute a callback to inform the second element it's done, but i'm not sure how to do that.

Moreover, i'm not really sure my general approach is appropriate or not.  I'm by no means a Polymer or web expert.  Just trying to have some fun! :-)

How would you recommend i handle this in Polymer?

Comment: Instead of `start.setAttribute()` and `appendChild()` create a property then you can bind to it and Polymer will update the value in the element it's bound to. You can register observers to get called when a bound property changes.

Comment: Doesn't change the intent of your comment, but i changed 'start' which was a typo to 'processed_data'.

Per you comment, i think you're suggesting a better way to load data into iron-meta elements.  I'll give that a go.  But, to make sure i'm understanding, i don't think you're suggesting this a a way to solve the problem of synchronization i'm describing. Let me know if i'm missing something.